# How to retrieve commits pushed into gerrit review?

Tags: git, gerrit

Changes are committed into gerrit (for code review) and accidentally deleted from work space.

Now, push from gerrit failed due to merge conflict.

Is there a way to retrieve the commit changes?

Answer (score 2):

You can fetch / checkout the change again from Gerrit into your local clone. You can find links for doing that at the right top: there is a menu "Download". Then you can copy these links and execute the commands in a terminal in your clone directory.

Answer (score 0):

In gerrit we normally have two screens

1). New Sreen

2). Old Screen (default).

First you need to check on which screen you are working on (**settings-> preferences -> Change View**:)

**For New Screen:**

There is one button of "Rebase" under Change details, simply click on that button, it will rebase your patch.

**For default screen:**

For each patchset, there will be one "Download" Menu, in front of which you will get all checkout/cherry-pick/patch etc options, select the cherry-pick option and click on the url. it would be like:

```
git fetch ssh://gerrit-url/project refs/changes/*/*****/* && git cherry-pick FETCH_HEAD
```

Just run this command to your terminal and you can made changes and upload back to gerrit, it will only increase the patchset of the same gerrit change.

**Note:** You can also change the Screen type based on ease of the solution.